# Mercurial - how to retrieve orig file after a revert?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I accidentally ran `hg revert` and lost all changes to my file `foo.js`. I see that a backup of the file exists as `foo.js.orig`. How can I add the orig file back so that I can reinstate my changes?

Update: I used `hg add foo.js.orig` to add the file back, but how can I replace the existing `foo.js` file with the original `foo.js.orig` file? I am new to mercurial so any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by:

1. Adding the file back using `hg add foo.js.orig`
2. Renaming the file using `hg rename -f foo.js.orig foo.js` (this replaces the existing-but-outdated foo.js file)

Answer (score 0):

You should just remove (or rename) `foo.js` and then rename `foo.js.orig` to `foo.js`. Then you can commit as normal.

`foo.js.orig` is not a tracked file in source control, and never needs to be.